# How can i add element and value in XML?

Tags: java, xml

I have this XML file:
(Actually, right now it is a StringBuffer, i don't want to save it to a file, i want to use it from the memory directly)

```
StringBuffer book =  
<book>
 <title>test</title>
 <bookinfo>
  <page>100</page>
 </bookinfo>
</book>
```

In here, i want to add a element and a value like this:

```
<book>
 <title>test</title>
 <bookinfo>
  <page>100</page>
  <price>100</price>
 </bookinfo>
</book>
```

what is the fast and easiest way to add an element and value in XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely want to familiarize yourself with javax.xml.

Here are some good tutorials:

- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html